# How to move TFS 2013 Background Job Agent cache to a different location

Tags: tfs

Our TFS 2013 cache is growing very large and would like to move it to a different hard drive. Looks like TFS has two caches, one for the web service and one for the background job agent so I wanted to move both. For the web service, it was very easy based on the description here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400793.aspx. For the job agent, I could not find a similar document, so I looked for a similar cache setting in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\TfsJobAgent.exe.config but couldn't find one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to move anything associated with the TfsJob Agent.

However when installing TFS there is the option to install to a different disk for everything. I would however not recommend this practice and you should have at least 100gb for a modern servers primary partition.